# Error in console while hiding the link on click through Polymer/Dom

Tags: dom, onclick, polymer

Hi Stack Overflowians,

I want to hide the `Click foo` link when I click the same `Click foo` link.

I have the following code:

```
<dom-module>
    <div id="foo">
        <a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click foo</a>
    </div>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: 'test-file',

        toggle_visibility: function(id) {
            var e = document.getElementById(id);

            if (e.style.display === "none") {
                e.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                e.style.display = "none";
            }
        });
</script>
</dom-module>
```

I get the error in Console tab when I click on `Click foo` link:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle_visibility is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick
```

I want the link to hide when clicked on `Click foo` link

Can anyone please help ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Polymer you declaratively add event handlers by using `on-` + the event name. So in your case that would be `on-click`, not `onclick`.

Also, you will need to provide the name for a method, not to call it. So your a tag would become something like:

```
<a href="#" on-click="toggle_visibility">Click foo</a>
```

Since that doesn't pass a paramter you can find another way, like using a `data-` attribute, or maybe if the relationship to the anchor is the same every time just rely on the fact that the div is the parent node:

```
toggle_visibility: function(event) {
    var e = event.currentTarget.parentNode;

    if (e.style.display === "none") {
        e.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        e.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**: also note that, if you go by using a method that would query for the element to toggle the display for, you will most likely have to query the shadowDom, not the document level. So

```
var e = document.getElementById(id);
```

would become:

```
var e = this.shadowRoot.getElementById(id);
```