# Error in console while validating gstin in Polymer JS

Tags: polymer

I have a Polymer JS code which validates GST Identification number:

```
<dom-module id="gst">
    <template>
            <div>
                <label for="gstid" class="gstlabel">GSTIN</label>
                <input type="text" id="gstid" name="gstid" on-submit="gstid_validation(gstid)">
            </div>
    </template>

    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: 'gst',
            gstid_validation: function(gstin) {
                var gstin_count = length(gstin);
                var pattern = "qr/\d{2}[A-Z]{5}\d{4}[A-Z][A-Z\d]Z[A-Z\d]/";
                if (gstin_count !== 15 && gstin !~ pattern) {
                    return 'Invalid GSTIN';
                }
            }.
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

I get the following error in console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token !
```

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error seems to be caused by `gstin !~ pattern`. What are you trying to achieve with that condition?

Comment: @mishu, The GST ID Number entered by the user should match with that pattern regex. I am checking if it doesnt match, then return the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment also, that is clearly a problem with the second part of your if statement, `gstin !~ pattern`.

Assuming that what you want is to match a regex the correct syntax would be something like:

```
if (gstin_count !== 15 && pattern.text(gstin))
```

Please note that there are several other issues with your code. Just to name a few:

- Your `pattern` variable holds a string, not a regex. For a regex you wouldn't use the quotations as delimiters. Also modifiers go at the end of regexes.
- In JS there's no `length` function, so if you don't have it customly
  implemented most likely you want gstin.length
- custom elements need to have dashes in their name (gstin-validator,    gst-in, etc),
- when you define an event handler you need to pass the method name, not to call it, like I told you in this other post: [Error in console while hiding the link on click through Polymer/Dom](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58480094/521598)